# How to identify when a process is triggered?

Tags: linux, process, command

I have a script in Linux (read-only partition that I cannot change or edit the file) that I want to know when this file is triggered by an external command (button connected to the device). This device is not a pc, so there is no keyboard, but I have telnet access as root.

I know what is and where is the file I want to monitor, but as I said in the beginning the partition is read-only and I cannot change it. Read-only partition is squashfs and would be easier if I could change the file, but as I said, I cannot change it.

So What I want is to find a way to "be informed" when this script is called, My aim is to identify who/how the script is called.

I've tried ps and top but the script runs to quickly to be identified for those and when I can find it using ps I do not know who triggered this script.

My idea is to monitor this script and when it is triggered I can run another command.

Script is located on /usr/bin/command

I do have access (read-write) to other partitions where I can put a script to run the second call.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might be able to use inotify, listening for access events.

Comment: You can use `mount --bind /tmp/myfile /usr/bin/command` to replace one file with another at the VFS level rather than the FS level. This does not require write access to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/bin/command`

Comment: inotify is not available and not sure if I will be able to install it, this hardware is very restricted.

Comment: the mount --bind option worked like a charm.
Thank you